# How do I add a string to each key of a dictionary?

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary where each key is composed of a string eg. `['ba']` and each value is list of numbers eg. `[1, 2, 3, 4,]`.

I would like to loop through each key and if the number is >= 100, I would like to add "D" in front of each number eg. 'D123, and if the number is <100, I would like to add "DI" to the front eg. 'DI45". I've written the following code but it doesn't change the dictionary.

```
def dict_change(dicto):
    for key,value in dicto.items():
        for numb in value:
            if numb >= 100:
                numb = 'D' + str(numb)
            else:
                numb = 'DI' + str(numb)
    return dicto

new_dict = dict_change(old_dict)
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: Please give an example of your input and the expected output.

Comment: A list can not be a dictionary key.

Comment: My current dictionary is set up as follows: {(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16): 'ba', (125, 126, 127, 128): 'pa'} and so forth. I wish for the output to be: {(DI11, DI12, DI13, DI14, DI15, DI16): 'ba', (D123, D126, D127, D128): 'pa'}. Thank you!

Comment: `list ` cannot be dictionary key but a `tuple` can and he has declared tuple in the example but for clarity please change in the question

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map` and a dict comprehension:

```
dct = {"a": [100, 200, 300], "b": [-100, 200, 100]}

def changer(number):
    char = "D" if number > 100 else "DI"
    return f"{char}{number}"


new_dct = {key: list(map(changer, values)) for key, values in dct.items()}
print(new_dct)
```

Output

```
{'a': ['DI100', 'D200', 'D300'], 'b': ['DI-100', 'D200', 'DI100']}
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def dict_change(dicto):
    modified_dict = {}
    for key,value in dicto.items():
        key_tuple = tuple((('D' if no>100 else 'DI')+ str(no) for no in key))
        modified_dict[key_tuple] = value
    return modified_dict


old_dict = {(110, 12, 13, 14, 15, 101): 'ba', (12, 126, -127, 128): 'pa'}
print(dict_change(old_dict))
```

Output

```
{('D110', 'DI12', 'DI13', 'DI14', 'DI15', 'D101'): 'ba', ('DI12', 'D126', 'DI-127', 'D128'): 'pa'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is most compact one-line way:

```
src = {(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16): 'ba', (125, 126, 127, 128): 'pa'}

d_out = {tuple(['Di','D'][i>100]+ str(i) for i in k):v for k,v in src.items()}

print(d_out)

Out[1]:
{('Di11', 'Di12', 'Di13', 'Di14', 'Di15', 'Di16'): 'ba',
 ('D125', 'D126', 'D127', 'D128'): 'pa'}
```

#### To make it clear

in a case if `i less than or equal 100` the 
`['DI','D'][i>100]` gives you `['DI','D'][False]` which interpreted as `['DI','D'][0]` and return `'DI'`

in a case if `i great than 100` the 
`['DI','D'][i>100]` gives you `['DI','D'][True]` which interpreted as `['DI','D'][1]` and return `'D'`

Comment: Very likely nobody will understand this code in a couple of weeks. No need for a one-liner, really.